# Using SharePoint MS Office features

Tags: web-services

Currently I have a document system that launches documents in Star Office or LibreOffice in an iframe.

Moving to the future I ideally want to retain the document system I have but integrate this into SharePoint so as to enable us to open and edit documents using MS Office.

As there is no Java Api to integrate with MS Office this is why I have chosen to go with SharePoint.

I can manage to get my documents to load from a link on a sharepoint page but then comes the hard part of manipulating the save features in MS Office and ensuring that my document doesn't get saved in sharepoint.

Has anyone done anything similar.

Basically I just want to use MS Office to interact with my documents without storing things in sharepoint. So I need to get access to the save functions etc.

Update: question has now been modified and asked on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937990/how-to-use-ms-office-with-proprietary-java-back-end-document-system).

Comment: I am struggling to decide whether SharePoint plays any part in this - in order to decide if it is on-topic.

Comment: Without SharePoint I don't think its possible to get the same MS Office functionality of opening, saving, editing the documents. As far as I see there is no Java API that allows you to do this similar to OpenOffice UNO API which allows you to do this with OpenOffice or LibreOffice

Comment: This feels like something you would do using VSTO or VBA. Another option might be exposing your document system as a WebDAV service. SharePoint feels like the wrong solution for what you are trying to achieve. I would re-phrase this question as "how to use MS Office with proprietary back-end document system" and post it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks, i posted new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16937990/how-to-use-ms-office-with-proprietary-java-back-end-document-system

Comment: Good. I'm closing this one and adding a link to SO. Hope you get a satisfactory solution.

Comment: much appreciated

Comment: I found this component that seems to do exactly what we require http://www.edrawsoft.com/officeviewer.php . I'm wondering are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding of your question is that you want to use SharePoint to view documents in a browser, without storing them on a server.

The primary function of SharePoint is to store documents on a server, and with some exceptions (Excel viewer) it doesn't provide a means to view documents in the browser. Unless I am misunderstanding your use case, I don't think that SharePoint is the right tool for your problem - it doesn't really do what you want even if you were to store the documents on the server.

Microsoft does have [Office Web Apps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431685%28v=office.14%29.aspx), but I think that would also require storing documents on a server somewhere (though I could be mistaken). At least with SP2013 I understand it's possible to integrate Office Web Apps with SharePoint to provide online viewing, but it's a separate product.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes I would like to use Office Web Apps in SharePoint ideally but i want to be able to manipulate the likes of the save function. When it clicks save I'd like to trap that in code somewhere and run my code to save the document in my database thus leaving the SQL database alone.

Comment: You could try using an HttpModule in SharePoint (or Office Web Apps itself if there's some mechanism to do so) to intercept requests; I can't speak for what the Office Web App requests look like but the Office Client integration requests get pretty complicated. Fiddler is a good tool for looking at the requests that get generated. But there might not be a way to intercept what you want.

Comment: You think then its possible to hook up SharePoint to use our IBM DB2 database. Maybe Biztalk server does this? Obviously it will leave out our Polarlake ESB BUS layer but it may be the only way to do this?